# How to form a matrix table

Tags: linux, matrix, text-files, tabular

File1 has the three columns. Column1 has groups, column2 has names of metabolic pathways belonging to a particular group, column3 has some values for each pathway:

```
 group1  pathway1  0.664   
 group1  pathway6  1  
 group1  pathway2  0.056  

 group2  pathway2  0.321  
 group2  pathway3  0.771
```

File2 has list of all the pathways:

```
 pathway1  
 pathway2  
 pathway3  
 pathway4  
 pathway5  
 pathway6
```

Output: How to obtain a matrix table that look like this:

```
          group1  group2    
pathway1  0.664
pathway2  0.056   0.321
pathway3          0.771
pathway4  
pathway5  
pathway6  1
```

Comment: please mention in which language you are trying ?

Comment: @MausamSinha I am a Linux beginner. Any not too complex solution will be appreciated!

Comment: Not only do you want people to write your code for you, but you're also posting the [same question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/350437/how-to-form-a-matrix-table) again and again to get more code.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev your point being...? because this community is not geared towards answering questions about coding and programming related?

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN { print "\t group1\tgroup2";b[1];b[2] }
     FNR==NR{ if ( $1 == "group1" ) a[$2"@"1]=$3;
              if ( $1 == "group2" ) a[$2"@"2]=$3 }
     FNR!=NR { printf $1" ";
               for ( j in b) { 
                   if ( $1"@"j in a) printf a[$1"@"j]"\t" ;
                   else printf "\t"};print "" }' File1 File2
```

Output:

```
         group1 group2
pathway1 0.664
pathway2 0.056  0.321
pathway3        0.771
pathway4
pathway5
pathway6 1
```

Answer (score 0):

File1 -> has 3 cols, File2 -> list of all pathways.

```
    perl -wMstrict -Mvars='*h' -lane '

       # Step: Gather data & populate the hash
       if ( @ARGV ) {
          next if @F < 3;
          my( $group, $pathway, $value ) = @F;
          $h{ $group }{ $pathway } = $value;
       } else {
          push @h, $_;
       }

       END{
          my @data;

          # Step: Prepare the tabular data
          for my $pathway ( @h ) {
             my @line = ( $pathway );

             for my $group ( sort keys %h ) {
                push @line, $h{ $group }{ $pathway } ||= q||;
             }

             push @data, [join ",", @line];
          }

          # Dynamiclly build the tbl template
          print for(
             q{.TS},

             join( ",", qw/ allbox center /, q/tab(,);/ ),

             ( "c " x (1+keys %h) ),

             ( qw/l/, "n " x (-1+keys %h), qw/n./ ),

             join( ",", q{}, sort keys %h ),

             join( "\n", map { @$_ } @data ),

             q{.TE},
          );
       }
' file1 file2 \
| tbl - | nroff -Tascii -ms | grep '.'
```

## Output

```
            +---------+--------+--------+
            |         | group1 | group2 |
            +---------+--------+--------+
            |pathway1 | 0.664  |        |
            +---------+--------+--------+
            |pathway2 | 0.056  | 0.321  |
            +---------+--------+--------+
            |pathway3 |        | 0.771  |
            +---------+--------+--------+
            |pathway4 |        |        |
            +---------+--------+--------+
            |pathway5 |        |        |
            +---------+--------+--------+
            |pathway6 | 1      |        |
            +---------+--------+--------+
```